# IllegalArgument Exception : Unable to compile

Tags: xpath, jdom-2

I am getting IlleagalArgument Exception while retreiving Xpath for a particular node

I need to retrieve the below webpage link which follows the title WebPages ,I  tried using the below expression but it is not able compile (Please see the comment section for the html )

```
page.getNode("//h3[. = 'Webpages:']/following-sibling::/ul[@class='list-entity-locations']/li/a/text()")
```

This is what I tried but got Exception

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to compile

Comment: <h3>Webpages</h3>                                                                                             
 <ul class="list-entity-locations"><li><a target="_blank" style="word-wrap: break-word;" href="http://www.ray-footandankleclinic.com">http://www.ray-footandankleclinic.com</a>                                                                                     </li>                                                                                                                         
         </ul>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right syntax is `following-sibling::ul`, not `following-sibling::/ul`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it , though it compiles now but I get null .

Comment: Then at least edit your question and provide minimal but complete samples of parsing the input and using XPath to allow others to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To looking into html which you have posted there is no `:` text inside `<h3>...</h3>` tag.
Try the below code.

```
//h3[. = 'Webpages']/following-sibling::ul[@class='list-entity-locations']/li/a/text()
```